# React is taking way more time for execution than expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, breadth-first-search, react-state

I have tried to implement [drench game](http://www.flashbynight.com/drench/). I have attached my code below. The logic is correct and it shouldn't also take so much time for execution given it is a 14x14 board. But after some clicks when the `state.covered` covers about quarter of the board the execution is taking way long to complete.

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const colors = ['aliceblue', 'tomato', 'darksalmon', 'thistle', 'olivedrab', 'steelblue']
  
  var dp = [];

  for(let i=0;i<14;i++){
    let temp = []
    for(let j=0;j<14;j++){
      temp[j] = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]
    }
    dp.push(temp)
  }
  

  var [state, setState] = useState({
    boardColors: dp,
    covered : [{x:0,y:0}],
  })

  var changeState = (color) => {

    var prevcolor = state.boardColors[0][0]
    var q = [...state.covered]
    var append_arr = [...state.covered]
    function isnotcovered(l,m,xt){
      for(let i=0;i<xt.length;i++){
        if(xt[i].x===l && xt[i].y===m){
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }

    var temp2D = [...state.boardColors];
      while(q.length){
        let top = q.shift()
        let l = top.x;
        let m = top.y;
        if( m-1>0 && temp2D[l][m-1]===prevcolor && isnotcovered(l,m-1,append_arr)){
          q.push({x:l,y:m-1})
          append_arr.push({x:l,y:m-1})
        }
        if(l+1<14  && temp2D[l+1][m]===prevcolor && isnotcovered(l+1,m,append_arr)){
          q.push({x:l+1,y:m})
          append_arr.push({x:l+1,y:m})
        }
        if(m+1<14 && temp2D[l][m+1]===prevcolor && isnotcovered(l,m+1,append_arr)){
          q.push({x:l,y:m+1})
          append_arr.push({x:l,y:m+1})
        }
        if(l-1>0 && temp2D[l-1][m]===prevcolor && isnotcovered(l-1,m,append_arr)){
          q.push({x:l-1,y:m})
          append_arr.push({x:l-1,y:m})
        }
      }

    setState((state) => ({boardColors : temp2D, covered : [...state.covered, ...append_arr]}) )
    
    setState((state) => updateState(state))
    
    function updateState(state){

      function isnotcovered(l,m,xt){
        for(let i=0;i<xt.length;i++){
          if(xt[i].x===l && xt[i].y===m){
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }

      var temp2D = [...state.boardColors];
      for(let i=0; i<state.covered.length; i++){
        temp2D[state.covered[i].x][state.covered[i].y]=color
      }
      var q = [...state.covered]
      var append_arr = [...state.covered]
      while(q.length){
        let top = q.shift()
        let l = top.x;
        let m = top.y;
        if( m-1>0 && temp2D[l][m-1]===color && isnotcovered(l,m-1,append_arr)){
          q.push({x:l,y:m-1})
          append_arr.push({x:l,y:m-1})
        }
        if(l+1<14  && temp2D[l+1][m]===color && isnotcovered(l+1,m,append_arr)){
          q.push({x:l+1,y:m})
          append_arr.push({x:l+1,y:m})
        }
        if(m+1<14 && temp2D[l][m+1]===color && isnotcovered(l,m+1,append_arr)){
          q.push({x:l,y:m+1})
          append_arr.push({x:l,y:m+1})
        }
        if(l-1>0 && temp2D[l-1][m]===color && isnotcovered(l-1,m,append_arr)){
          q.push({x:l-1,y:m})
          append_arr.push({x:l-1,y:m})
        }
      }
      return {
        boardColors : temp2D,
        covered : [...state.covered, ...append_arr],
      }
    }
  }

  
  return (
    <>
      <Board colors2D={state.boardColors} />
      <Controls boardColors={state.boardColors} colors2D={state.boardColors} colors={colors} color='green' changeState={changeState}/>
    </>
  );
}


function Board(props){
  var boardStyle = {
    height: '280px',
    aspectRatio: '1',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'
  }
  var display = props.colors2D.map((color1D, index1) => (color1D.map((color,index2) => <div key={14*index1 + index2} style={{width:'20px', aspectRatio: '1', backgroundColor: color, float: 'left'}}></div>)))
  return(
    <div style={boardStyle}>
      {display}
    </div>
  )
}

function Controls(props){
  var controlStyle = {
    height: '200px',
    width: '300px',
    backgroundColor: props.color
  }

  var handleClick = (color) => {
    props.changeState(color)
  }
  var buttons = props.colors.map((color, index) => <button key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(color)}>{color}</button>)
  
  return(
    <>
      <div style={controlStyle}>
        {buttons}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default App;
```

replace this code in `App.js` and it should work fine

Comment: Don't `shift()` an array! It takes `O(n)` time, `O(n^2)` if you use it in a loop.

Comment: but `n` in this case is 14. so, will it matter

Comment: It's the length of `state.covered` (I don't know how long that is).

Comment: Max length for `state.covered` is 14*14(196)

Comment: So, if `n = 196`, `n^2 = 38,416`...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the problem by doing a `console.log` of your state everytime it changes:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);
```

Everytime you click on a color button (even if it's the same), the displayed state shows an array as value of the `covered` key that gets its size multiplied by 4.

This is because you are copying the content of covered boxes in `append_arr` variable:

```
var append_arr = [...state.covered]
```

And when the computing is done you append the content of `state.covered` and the content of `append_arr` into `state.covered`:

```
covered : [...state.covered, ...append_arr],
```

This makes it at least double at every click.

You should assign only the result of `append_arr` as the new covered state:

```
covered : [...append_arr],
```

And the reason it actually quadruples is because you are doing this twice, with 2 functions `changeState` and `updateState` doing more or less the same thing and called each time.

You are callign `setState` twice. This can't be useful because the result of the first call will be applied only when the whole function finishes. You should remove one of the occurrences:

```
    /* removing this one
    setState((state) => ({boardColors : temp2D, covered : [...state.covered, ...append_arr]}) ) */
    
    setState((state) => updateState(state))
```

Comment: Yeah, I realised it. Thanks a lot!